# Grotrian diagram for Helium

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, orbitals

[image]

Hi, is this Grotrian diagram for helium wrong? I can't understand how a $1s2d$ state is possible since my understanding was that the $d$ states only start at $n=3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. This seems to be a typo.
The term should be labeled $1s3d$, not $1s2d$.

See for example this Helium Grotrian diagram
taken from lecture notes by [astro.caltech.edu - SR Kulkarni - Ay126 Helium](https://sites.astro.caltech.edu/%7Esrk/Ay126/Lectures/Lecture4/Helium.pdf).
[image]